# How to configure Nginx-Ingress rules with Keycloak

Tags: nginx, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes v1.26 self-managed cluster. I have multiple applications exposed through the [Nginx-ingress proxy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx).

I want to protect the access to those apps through authentification, I found Keycloak and deployed it with the [bitnami chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/keycloak/helm), version `docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:20.0.5-debian-11-r4`. I have created a realm `services` and a client `nginx` in this realm. (I'm not completely confident on what this represents)

Now I'm stuck at updating my ingress rules to force authentification when accessing my apps.
I found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/#example-oauth2-proxy-kubernetes-dashboard) an example with oauth to add the following annotations:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
```

I tried multiple combinations of `$host`, `/auth` `/realms/services`, I couldn't find the correct endpoint so far and all requests are redirected to a 404.

On the client page in Keycloak, there are Client id and secret, but I didn't find any nginx annotation to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help anyone in that situation:

I found this similar [question](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548562/what-is-proper-design-for-authentication-in-kubernetes-using-nginx-ingress-and-k). From my understanding, Nginx cannot communicate with Keycloak directly, and oauth2 proxy is not able to replace nginx functionnality to manage the kubernetes ingresses.

I made it work with the following :

[oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) deployed. I didn't find any deployment example, here's what I did:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: oauth2-proxy
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8091
        args:
        - --provider=keycloak-oidc
        - --client-id=nginx
        - --client-secret=###
        - --cookie-secret=###=
        - --oidc-issuer-url=https://###/realms/test
        - --oidc-extra-audience=account
        - --scope=openid
        - --pass-authorization-header=true
        - --pass-access-token=true
        - --pass-user-headers=true
        - --set-authorization-header=true
        - --set-xauthrequest=true
        - --cookie-refresh=1m
        - --cookie-expire=30m
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:8091
        - --code-challenge-method=S256
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kc
  labels:
    name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8091
  selector:
    app: oauth2-proxy

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kc
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ###
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /oauth2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: oauth2-proxy
                port:
                  number: 8091
```

And the Nginx ingress annotations for resources to be protected :

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://###/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://###/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
```